# How to move an image when clicked on it in PYGAME?

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

Basically, when I click on an image I want the image to move to a new different location. When I click again, it should move again.

```py
import pygame
import random

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1420, 750))

pygame.display.set_caption("Soccer Game")
icon = pygame.image.load('soccer-ball-variant.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)


ball = pygame.image.load('soccer2.png')
ballrect = ball.get_rect()

X = random.randrange(0, 1100)
Y = random.randrange(0, 600)

def player():
    screen.blit(ball, (X, Y))

run = True
while run:
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            x, y = event.pos
            if ball.get_rect().collidepoint(x, y):
                X = random.randrange(0, 1100)
                Y = random.randrange(0, 600)
                player()



    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
    player()

    pygame.display.update()
```

The problem is that this program only works when i click on the left-up corner of the screen, and not on the ball. I am a biginner in the pygame module, but i think the problem is this if statement:

```py
if ball.get_rect().collidepoint(x, y):
    X = random.randrange(0, 1100)
    Y = random.randrange(0, 600)
    player()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`pygame.Surface.get_rect.get_rect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_rect) returns a rectangle with the size of the *Surface* object, that always starts at (0, 0) since a *Surface* object has no position. A *Surface* is `blit` at a position on the screen. The position of the rectangle can be specified by a keyword argument. For example, the top leftof the rectangle can be specified with the keyword argument `topleft`. These keyword argument are applied to the attributes of the [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) before it is returned (see [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) for a full list of the keyword arguments).

<s>`if ball.get_rect().collidepoint(x, y):`</s>

```py
if ball.get_rect(topleft = (X, Y)).collidepoint(x, y):
```

However, I recommend removing the `X` and `Y` variables, but using `ballrect` instead:

```py
ballrect = ball.get_rect()
ballrect.x = random.randrange(0, 1100)
ballrect.y = random.randrange(0, 600)

def player():
    screen.blit(ball, ballrect)
```

```py
if ballrect.collidepoint(event.pos):
    ballrect.x = random.randrange(0, 1100)
    ballrect.y = random.randrange(0, 600)
```

---

Complete example:

```py
import pygame
import random

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1420, 750))
pygame.display.set_caption("Soccer Game")
icon = pygame.image.load('soccer-ball-variant.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

ball = pygame.image.load('soccer2.png')
ballrect = ball.get_rect()
ballrect.x = random.randrange(0, 1100)
ballrect.y = random.randrange(0, 600)

def player():
    screen.blit(ball, ballrect)

run = True
while run: 
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if ballrect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                ballrect.x = random.randrange(0, 1100)
                ballrect.y = random.randrange(0, 600)

    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
    player()
    pygame.display.update()
```